# Quick drain of battery in new phone huawei g play mini?

Tags: battery, charging, huawei, battery-history

[image: Battery History]
Here is a screenshot of my battery drain.

Is it normal , or should I go to service center ? My previous phone had much less sloppier curve . When I bought the phone I charged it upto 100% and then started using it , though at the shop they told me to charge for 3 hours. Should I go to service center? The problem is battery(2500mA) is fixed in this device , so I can't even remove it.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your screenshot I think you should wait a few days to see if your new device settles down a bit on battery usage.

Why do I say that?

Even though your battery is draining fast when your screen is off, there are **not many wakelocks**. Give your phone a little bit off time to settle down ( syncing data between all accounts etc.) and it should be fine. If you're still observing heavy battery drain after 2-3 days, then you should go to the service center.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me to 'till yesterday. My battery was draining really quick and I went to "notifications administrator" and turn off almost every notification.

The fact is that battery is not drainin' so fast. Only 15% since yesterday, so for me it worked!

Comment: I only see notification center in my device , and I 'restricted' almost all app..  ,  what else did you do ?

Comment: I only did that. Restricted all notifications except the ones I really need. It seemed to work. Since I bought the phone the battery life was like 1 day and a few hours , right now its 49% and almost beatin' the record (its on for 24h) :P
Try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off "Scanning always available" and "network notification" and my issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar problem on this set, it is solved during 15 minutes at service center and its now 4 month working fine. So I suggest you to visit Service center

Sudat